# android get button background imageName programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-relativelayout

I'm using button in layout.xml as following

```
 <Button
      android:id="@+id/karaza"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="160dp"
      android:background="@drawable/button_green"
      android:text="0"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="45dp" />
```

The background image name is "button_green"

how can I get it in the code of activity as String?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you tell where are you using it and why ??

Comment: I want to use the name of the background to check if the name of background is "green" to use other green background image in the press action. and so on with other colors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054414/726863

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I donot think there is any direct way to get name of drawable image unless you stores the image name along with image.

In XML you can do the following to set image name as an additional data to imageview

```
android:tag="btful.png"
```

Programmetically setting imagename

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id.img)// my image
img.settag("btful.png"); // to set an image name
```

you can get the image name by using getTag()

```
 String imageName = (String)img.getTag();
```

Comment: My background is not "Color" it is a png image in the drawable folder and I want to retrieve its name as String

Comment: ok thanks for your help, it seems no way to get the imagr directly so I'll think in alternatives.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
Btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_green);
```

Comment: This is to set the background to the btn, this is not my mean. I want to retrieve the background name in the code

Answer (score -1):

Just Findviewbyid of button in java file then use:

```
  btn.getBackground();
```

it'll work!!

and assign it to a drawable ...

Comment: I tried this and bit prints this --> android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@4053a870 and this is not the image name that it is "button_green"

Comment: its the id of that button u can use it instead of name

Comment: Try out this ...it will work definately:                           String btnName = getResources().getString(R.id.btnid);